# Free word list for word game

Tags: online-game, word-list

I am building a word game in English. Is there a free list of words that I can download and use of a free service that can help validate the word entered by the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out The Oxford 3000™ 
http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/wordlist/english/oxford3000/

or get it from https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/word-lists

or you can check out this https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words.txt